# how to convert and compare some data from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to compare some data from different databases. I think to use MINUS operator for this comparison. However, I have some difficult with a conversion. For instance how to convert number - 91108234116 from RAW() toward VARCHAR2(). Could you please tell me how to convert the data below. I use PL/SQL developer.

[image]

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For **conversion** can you try this:

```
select 
    cast(raw_column as varchar2(11))
    from table1;
```

Then you can compare by equality operator '**=**'.

Here's a [conversion matrix](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_cast.htm) for other data types.